# Load Excel files with different format using SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

We have a problem where we have to load different excel file templates , here are the templates

**Template # 1  :** 
Name Address City Zip

**Template # 2 :**
Name City State Address Phone Number

We don't know what format we can get , using SSIS how can I load excel files where column name are changing dynamically?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that there will be only 2 distinct template types that you get, you can follow the below approach:

1. Create a script task in control flow. Add the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library in references. This task will be used to read the Excel file before starting actual ETL operations.
2. Create a new variable, say templateType. This will be used to show which template is used by current input  file.
3. Create 2 data flow tasks - one for each of the 2 distinct templates.
4. Connect the script task outputs to the data flows. In each connection, set the precedence constraint evaluation type to expression and set expression to     @templateType==ValueToRepresentTemplateType
5. Edit the script task using below code as reference:

   ```
       //using excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

       excel.Application xlapp = null;
       excel.Workbook xlbook = null;
       excel.Worksheet xlsheet = null;

       string src = @"filename.xls";

       try
       {
           xlapp = new excel.Application();
           xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(src, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
           xlsheet = (excel.Worksheet) xlbook.Worksheets[0];


           //If fifth cell is empty, template has 4 columns i.e. first template
           excel.Range decider = (excel.Range)xlsheet.Cells[1, 5];
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(decider.Text.ToString()))
           {
               Dts.Variables["User::templateType"].Value = 1;//first template
           }
           else
           {
               Dts.Variables["User::templateType"].Value = 2;//second template
           }

   xlbook.Close(false);
   xlapp.Quit();

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
       }
       finally
       {
           xlsheet = null;
           xlbook = null;
           xlapp = null;
       }
       Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
   ```